# Visual Studio Code Activity bar completely missing, Version 1.28

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just downloaded VSCode, ver 1.28 and the activity bar (left side) and the left side of the side bar are not there.   This happened yesterday too, so uninstalled the program and tried again today.
I have no way to get to settings, debug, search, etc.  Tried right clicking on black space and they don't show up, merely options to open a new file.  If I do open (untitled) I still do not get that left part of the screen.  I am comparing it to MS's user interface page (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface).   Is it possible that I would have to change the resolution on my laptop?
Thanks.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: Or from command palette: `View: Toggle Activity Bar Visibility`

Comment: Thank you so much, Alex!  I am new to using editors - and coding.   Was only trying to follow a Python for Beginners tutorial and I couldn't make it past the setup.  Have a good one.

Answer (score 47):

From the menu bar at the top try

**View/Apperance/Show Activity Bar**

When the Activity Bar is visible, this option will show "Hide Activity Bar"

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5ClT.png)

Answer (score 5):

Another way to loose Activity Bar is to accidently active Zen Mode. Check if

**View/Apperance/Zen Mode**

is checked and if so uncheck it.

Answer (score 4):

1. Simply go to the setting.
2. Under the user settings search for Activity Bar.
3. You'd find it under the workbench.
4. Click the Activity bar visible and that's green and working.

Answer (score 4):

You can also pull up the command pallet with

`Ctrl + Shift + P` (Windows/Linux)

`Cmd + Shift + P` (Mac)

Then type/select

`View: Toggle Activity Bar Visibility`